# How to reload Table View with different data from the original?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I have `UIViewController` with header(View contains Image + Label) and  Table View with custom cell with an image and label.

In the `didSelectRowAt indexPath` I wrote this code to reveal to another view if the button `Home` 
but if the button selected is `Offers` I want to reload `tableview` with a new data not the original data .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let revealViewController: SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController()


    let cell: MenuTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell


    let MenuStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if cell.labelCell.text! == "Home"
    {
        let DestVC = MenuStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
        let newFrontVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: DestVC)

        revealViewController.pushFrontViewController(newFrontVC, animated: true)
    }
    // OffersTableVC
    if cell.labelCell.text! == "Offers"
    {

        // reload a new data different from the original array


    }
```

So is this possible ?

Comment: There are lots of animation, so which animation you are using pls specify.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy forget about the animation I need to reload the table view with new data different data

Comment: Your question is supposed to be totally changed

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy so could you please change it !

Comment: No, I mean few days before you askd something different and now asking something different.

Comment: Answer of current question is..yeah! we easily do it. But you didn't specify where the button `Home` and `Offers` added. I mean location of these buttons.

Comment: the locations are in the table view

Comment: Can you post your Cell screenShot?

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy go a head this a screenshot of the Main menu contains Home and Offers

Comment: Your condition is worng.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133261/discussion-between-mohammad-eliass-alhusain-and-the-dahiya-boy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do code like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell : TblCellTimeline = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TblCellTimeline

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // do code for home
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1{
            // do code for offer                
        }
        :
        :
        else{
            return
        }


    }
```

Comment: go to the chat please